# How do I obtain the exit code for a (Java) process with the Win32 API?

Tags: windows, winapi, jvm, status, termination

How can I obtain the JVM exit code (value of 'status' from call: System.exit(status)) from a Windows program which started this JVM? I tried to use result from the ShellExecute() call, but the result (42) was independent of real value of status.

Answer (score 2):

Start the external application by using ShellExecuteEx instead of ShellExecute.

Before calling ShellExecuteEx, enable the SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS flag in the parameter to the ShellExecuteEx function. You will then receive a handle to the started process in the hProcess field of the parameter to the ShellExecuteEx function.

ShellExecuteEx: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154(VS.85).aspx

Then, use the WaitForSingleObject function or any other WaitFor* function to wait until the external application is terminated.

WaitForSingleObject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx

Then, use the GetExitCodeProcess function to read the exit code of the external process.

GetExitCodeProcess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thank You. Eventually I changed the idea of my java program executed from my main program, so now there is no need to obtain the jvm exit code.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) for that function make it quite clear that it does not return the exit codes from the called application.

> If the function succeeds, it returns a
>   value greater than 32. If the function
>   fails, it returns an error value that
>   indicates the cause of the failure.
>   The return value is cast as an
>   HINSTANCE for backward compatibility
>   with 16-bit Windows applications. It
>   is not a true HINSTANCE, however. It
>   can be cast only to an int and
>   compared to either 32 or the following
>   error codes below.

There appears to be some example code for [getting exit status](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446835(VS.85).aspx) at MSDN as well.